# PDOに関するエラーが解決できない。

Tags: php, mysql

失礼します。
一つ前のページから値をいくつか持ってきて、それらを合わせてSQL文にし実行するためのコードを書いています。
エラー内容は以下の通りです。

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter
>   number: parameter was not defined in
>   C:\phpdocs\ec\syaeikan\rs\result.php on line 138

プレースホルダにバインドする値の数が合っていないというエラーなのでしょうか。
自分では解決できなかったので、どこが間違っていて、どう直せばよいのかを教えていただきたいです。

コードは以下の通りです。

```
    //DB情報取得
    include "db.php";

    if(!isset($_SESSION['es'])){
        $_SESSION['es'] = array();
    }

    //クエリ前半準備
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM t_goods_tbl,t_maker_tbl WHERE';

    $sql_color = "";
    $sql_maker = "";

    //POSTデータの受信
    //色指定
    for($i=1;$i<=14;$i++){
        if(isset($_POST[$i])){
            $color[] = $_POST[$i];
        }
    }
    var_dump($color);

    $count_c = count($color);

    for($i=0;$i<$count_c;$i++){
        if($i!="0"){
            $sql_color = $sql_color." OR ";
        }
        $sql_color = $sql_color."f_goods_color=:color".$color[$i];
    }
    var_dump($sql_color);

    //メーカー指定
    for($i=16;$i<=20;$i++){
        if(isset($_POST[$i])){
            $maker[] = $_POST[$i];
        }
    }
    var_dump($maker);

    $count_m = count($maker);

    for($i=0;$i<$count_m;$i++){
        if($i!="0"){
            $sql_maker = $sql_maker." OR ";
        }
        $sql_maker = $sql_maker." f_goods_maker=:maker".$maker[$i];
    }
    var_dump($sql_maker);



    //セッションの中身を変数に移す
    if(isset($_SESSION['es'])){
        $es = $_SESSION['es'];
    }
    var_dump($es);

    //sql文の用意
if($count_c != 0){
    if($count_m != 0){
        //色指定もメーカー指定もある場合
        $query = $query.$es."AND ".$sql_color." AND".$sql_maker;
    }else{
        //色指定のみある場合
        $query = $query.$es."AND".$sql_color;
    }
}else if($count_m != 0){
    //メーカー指定のみある場合
    $query = $query = $query.$es."AND".$sql_maker;
}else{
    //色、メーカー指定が無い場合
    $query = $query.$es;
}

var_dump($query);

//SQL実行処理
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
if($count_c != 0){
    for($i=0;$i<$count_c;$i++){
        $holder = ':color'.$i;
        $stmt->bindParam($holder,$color[$i],PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
    if($count_m != 0){
        for($i=0;$i<$count_m;$i++){
            $holder_2 = ':maker'.$i;
            $stmt->bindParam($holder_2,$maker[$i],PDO::PARAM_STR);      
        }
        //色指定もメーカー指定もある場合
        $stmt->execute();
    }else{
        //色指定のみある場合
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}else if($count_m != 0){
        for($i=0;$i<$count_m;$i++){
            $holder_2 = ':maker'.$i;
            $stmt->bindParam($holder_2,$maker[$i],PDO::PARAM_STR);      
        }
        //メーカー指定のみある場合
        $stmt->execute();
}else{
    //色、メーカー指定が無い場合
    $stmt->execute();
}

$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

line138に当たる部分は

> //色指定もメーカー指定もある場合
>             $stmt->execute();

こちらです。
前後のコードや途中の関係ないであろう一部のコードは除いています。
勉強中の身とはいえコードが汚くて申し訳ないですが、改善点を教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

追記：
dumpの出力結果です。

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string '2' (length=1)
  1 => string '4' (length=1)
  2 => string '7' (length=1)

string 'f_goods_color=:color2 OR f_goods_color=:color4 OR f_goods_color=:color7' (length=71)

array (size=1)
  0 => string '10' (length=2)

string ' f_goods_maker=:maker10' (length=23)

string ' f_goods_price <= 10000 ' (length=24)

string 'SELECT * FROM t_goods_tbl,t_maker_tbl WHERE f_goods_price <= 10000 AND f_goods_color=:color2 OR f_goods_color=:color4 OR f_goods_color=:color7 AND f_goods_maker=:maker10' (length=169)
```

Comment: エイリアスやJOINといったものの知識が無いので、勉強してみたいと思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

質問を投稿してすぐで申し訳ないのですが、エラーを改善できてしまった事と新たな問題点の発覚がありましたので、自分で回答をさせていただきます。

今回のエラーは

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter
>   number: parameter was not defined in
>   C:\phpdocs\ec\syaeikan\rs\result.php on line 138
>   というものでした。
>   原因は、

```
if($count_c != 0){
    for($i=0;$i<$count_c;$i++){
        $holder = ':color'.$i;
        $stmt->bindParam($holder,$color[$i],PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
```

このコードの3行目でした。
コードの上の方で、

```
$sql_color = $sql_color."f_goods_color=:color".$color[$i];
```

と、$color[$i]と書いていたにも関わらず指定するときには$iのみになっていたので、値が一致していなかったのです。

原因を探ってくださった方、ありがとうございました。